# How to make centered 50px x 50px photos in a row from different resolutions (e.g 136px x 266px)

Tags: html, css

So I need to make 50px x 50px photos in a row. All of them have different resolutions. My question is how to scale photos down to make them 50px x 50px with centered content, just like in Photoshop where I can make a 50x50 square and move it to choose where to copy.
**50x50 square:**
[image]

**ON THE LEFT:** This is the original photo for example it is 136px x 266px
**ON THE RIGHT:** This is how photos should look like
[image]

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: Actually im trying to write this 3 hours, nothing worked so far thats why i decided to write here. The only thing left is to crop the image in PhotoShop as people below said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically it would be best to crop your images in something like PhotoShop **before** uploading them to your website. This is due to the fact that the user will have to download the photos, and smaller dimensions for a photo means a smaller filesize (and thus a quicker download for your user).

If you **have** to crop the photos on the website itself, you can use the [**`clip` property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) in conjunction with `position: absolute`:

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 80px, 200px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/200">
```

Note that the `clip` property is **deprecated** (because you should be cropping the image beforehand), and may be removed at any time.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge this is not something possible in css because css can only resize and move the image, but cannot crop the image. The image on the right is not simply resized but is cropped to focus on the persons face and that is something css cannot do as it can't modify the image content. You can find good free online cropping tools to resize your image or use the cropper that comes with windows 10 in settings when you view an image.